Почему unity пытается установить платформу android-31 при целевой платформе android-35?
При сборке проекта получаю следующую ошибку:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.


What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:generateReleaseRFile'.


Failed to install the following SDK components:
platforms;android-31 Android SDK Platform 31
The SDK directory is not writable (C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\6000.0.23f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK)

Входные данные: до этого над проектом работал другой разработчик. Он устанавливал плагин Google Admob но не интегрировал его в код.
Когда я взял проект, самого плагина в нём не было(не был засунут в git), плагин использовался только в скриптах-заготовках под разные типы рекламы(Rewarded, Interstitial).
Я удалил эти файлы и проект не выдавал ошибок, но не собирался, выдавая вышеуказанную ошибку. Я удалил Google Admob и проект стал собираться. Сейчас я сам установил Google Admob, интегрировал его в код и получаю эту ошибку.
В Project Settings > Player установлен Minimum API Level 23 и Target API Level 35.
Как я понимаю, осталась какая-то старая зависимость от другой версии какого-то плагина(admob)… Как её удалить?
